# System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES() is not defined in .NET Standard

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, .net-standard

I am converting a vb.net library to .NET Standard and I am getting 'System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES is not defined'

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography  

Shared Function Encode(ByVal value As String, _
                       ByVal key As String) As String
    Dim mac3des As New System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES()
    Dim md5 As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    mac3des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
    Return Convert.ToBase64String( _
      System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)) & "-"c & _
      Convert.ToBase64String(mac3des.ComputeHash( _
      System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)))
End Function
```

Is there a way to fix this as it didn't generate an error in the 4.7.1 framework library

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What exactly do you think a "fix" for that would look like? If that type is not defined in .NET Standard then either don't use it or don't target .NET Standard. I think you ought to do some reading and learn exactly what .NET Standard is, because it doesn't sound like you know.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It's actually the inverse as I can assume the intent of System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES(), but figured encoding would occur irrelevant of platform. To give context, the code was not done by me (I only have been coding for 2.5 weeks to where most of my posts here are within that range); I figured I needed to have a hand in all aspects of my company so coding is my one noticeable weakness.  As for a fix I figured an alternative reference, but you have a point about researching MACTripleDES to understand it's purpose.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MACTripleDES is a fairly uncommon algorithm it was not ported to .NET Core; and therefore is not part of .NET Standard.  (HMACSHA1 is used in NuGet packages 20 times for each time MACTripleDES is used, and HMACSHA256 is 10:1)

The concept is fairly simple: `TripleDES.Create()`, set the IV to `new byte[8]`, the key to your key, and the PaddingMode to Zeros (or whatever you set it to in your usage).  Then run all your data through it, and the last 8 bytes are the MAC.

The .NET Framework code is available on [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/mactripledes.cs,26200fc6e34cc8b4) if your project is amenable to the [MS-RSL license](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/mactripledes.cs,26200fc6e34cc8b4).

Comment: Thank you so much.  It provided the insight that I was looking, helped clear the error that was generated as well as find an appropriate alternative with TripleDES.Create() that works in .NET Standard

Comment: @McCarson How did you exactly do it ? as i am having trouble using TripleDES, you just create TripleDES and that what its done? can you please share code snipet how its done ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to implement your own version of MACTripleDES using TripleDES.Create()

```
 public static string ComputeMACTripleDES(string request, string hexPlainKey)
    {
        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(request);
        var key = Convert.FromBase64String(hexPlainKey);

        // Create a TripleDES object with the specified key and IV set to zero
        using (TripleDES tdes = TripleDES.Create())
        {
            tdes.Key = key;
            tdes.IV = new byte[8];
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Create an encryptor and a memory stream
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = tdes.CreateEncryptor())
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Write the data to the memory stream using the encryptor
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                // Get the encrypted data from the memory stream
                byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();

                // Return the last 8 bytes as the MAC
                byte[] mac = new byte[8];
                Array.Copy(encryptedData, encryptedData.Length - 8, mac, 0, 8);
                //return mac;
                var sign = Convert.ToBase64String(mac);
                return sign;
            }
        }
    }
```